# How do you remove a trailing decimal zero in middle of string?

Tags: javascript, regex

Suppose I have a string: "Trump spent $1.50 billion dollars for his campaign."

How would I remove the trailing zero?

I thought `str.replace('/(\.[0-9]{1})0+\s/g',"$1");` would work but doesn't strip it.  Any help please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to use a regex (`/.../g`), but you're actually using a string literal (`'/.../g'`). Remove the `'`s:

```
str.replace(/(\.[0-9]{1})0+\s/g, "$1");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
str.replace(/(\.[0-9]*[^0])0+/g, "$1");
```

This will handle cases like `$1.040` or `$1.120` as well.

Answer (score 0):

parse every float and stringify it again:

```
str.replace(/\d+\.\d+/g, Number);
```